# iPhone - In App Purchase questions

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Merry Christmas. I have two questions on In App Purchase.

1. iAP application process: do I need to submit my iAP items applications, wait for Apple's responses, then build my app accordingly, or, I can just create some iAP items, build them into my app, then after everything's done, submit my binary to Apple?
2. Intermediary currency: on Apple's documentation I found these sentences:

> "You may not offer items that represent **intermediary currency** because it is important that users know the specific good or service that they are buying."

However, I found a few apps on the App Store offering its users with different kinds of intermediary currency. I'm confused. Is this a gray area in which we developers can play some tricks?

Thanks in advance.

Di

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to add in-app purchases to iTunes Connect, and wait for apple approval to be able to sell them from real application.
   However, you can debug/test them without that approval, via sandbox environment.
2. I cannot say a lot about that 'intermediary currency' and what Apple actually mean. A lot of games uses in-app purchases to sell in-game 'coins', and everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks Nickolay for your prompt reply.